Loophole custom domain stops working regularly
I wascreating Loophole creation using the following line of code:
loophole http 7777

Everything was working pretty well many times for multiple days. Then I found out at I can set a specific host name and started using the following lone of code:
loophole http 7777 --hostname test_hostname

The problem is that this stops working multiple times a day. Is there a reason for that? I really need a static website, cause I would need to change it in many devices manually otherwise
